# Passing in id's when rendering form using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using ajax to render a form partial into #image_form when a user clicks this button:

```
<%= link_to image_form_path, :remote => true do %>
  <div class="button">Add Image</div>
<% end %>

 <div id="image_form">
 </div>
```

The image_form partial:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@post, Comment.new] %>
```

The controller:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])    
end
```

and image_form.js.erb looks like this:

```
 $("#image_form").html("<%= j render :partial=>'comments/image_form' %>");
```

I have two models: posts and comments (comments belong to posts). If I render the form normally `<%= render 'comments/image_form' %>`, posting works. When I render using ajax the post id (and maybe the comment id also) aren't passed in giving me this url and a 'no routes' error.

```
localhost:3000/posts//comment
```

What's different about rendering it using ajax that the id's aren't passed in?

Comment: Would you add the code in controller for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can change partial to

```
<%= simple_form_for [post, Comment.new] %>
```

and change `image_form.js.erb` to

```
$("#image_form").html("<%= j render(partial: 'comments/image_form', locals: {post: @post}) %>");
```

Partial do not have access to the `@post` variable directly.

Comment: Hmm, no luck. Still getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: You have to check your `@post` and `post` exists/not null in your controller/js.erb/partial one by one then.